# How to create random numbers with exceptions and that do not repeat themselves

Tags: swift

I would like to know how to make an app generate a random number with numbers determined by typing in UITextField, for example, between 25 and 35, but that do not repeat and that can not display some numbers, also determined by typing in UITextField, for example : 28, 29 and 30.
So by pressing the button he would have the numbers 25, 26, 27, 31, 32, 33, 34 and 35 to display (remembering that without repeating)

I've tried several places and courses, but I did not get a valid answer.

Comment: Use `Int.random()` to generate random numbers. Use `Set<Int>` to store those number that aren't blacklisted. Repeat until the set has the desired number of entries.

Comment: Geting all numbers in a given range, with some exceptions, doesn’t sound very random to me

Answer (score 1):

Create a set of values that you want to include

```
let allValues = Set(25...35)
```

Create a list of values you don't want to include

```
let exceptions = [28, 29, 30]
```

Remove the values you don't want

```
let valuesToUse = values.subtracting(exceptions)
```

Shuffle the order

```
let randomValues = valuesToUse.shuffled()
```

You can now use `randomValues` in order to provide a random list of desired values that do not repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of your numbers and an array of numbers you don't want

```
let array1 = Array(25...35)
let array2 = Array(28...30)
```

remove the number you don't want using to create the final array

```
let correctArray = Array(Set(array1).subtracting(array2))
```

After that make this function for random number without repetition

```
func extract() {
    let count = correctArray.count

    while count > 1 {
         let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0 ... count)
         let extractedNumber = correctArray[randomNumber]
         correctArray[count] = correctArray[randomNumber]
         count -= 1
    }
}
```

Comment: resulted in this, Francesco,
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).